Trying to load a clicked link's href into a div doesnt work
I changed the jQuery version from 3.6.0 to 3.6.3 and I get an error when I use the load function.
I have the below code


$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.nav, #menu').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#content').load($(this).attr('href'));
  });
});
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
  <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-bs-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" data-bs-target="#submenu-3" aria-controls="submenu-3">Practice</a>
  <div id="submenu-3" class="collapse">
    <ul class="nav nav-small flex-column">

      <li class="nav-item">
        <a id="menu" class="nav-link" href="practise.php">Practice</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a id="menu" class="nav-link" href="statistics.php">Statistics</a>
      </li>

    </ul>
  </div>
</li>



and I get the below error
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'indexOf')
    at jQuery.fn.load (jquery-3.6.3.js:10473:13)
    at HTMLUListElement.<anonymous> (dashboard.php:64:19)
    at HTMLUListElement.dispatch (jquery-3.6.3.js:5494:27)
    at elemData.handle (jquery-3.6.3.js:5298:28)

If I change the jQuery version to 3.6.0 the error disappears. If I change the version of jQuery to 3.6.1, 3.6.2, or 3.6.3 I get the above error.
Is anything wrong with my code?
I tried different versions of jquery and I get the same error.

What does console.log($(this).attr('href')) show when this happens?

I get exercises.php or todo.php . No extra error

I compared 3.6.0 and 3.6.1 and don't see any difference around that code. I think it's the line off = url.indexOf( " " );, where url is the argument to load(). So I don't see how it can happen unless $(this).attr('href') is undefined.

Agreed with @Barmar here. the code will work flawlessly irrespective of versions in case of $(this).attr('href') is coming fine. In case it is undefined then the error will come in both jQuery versions.

Hello all, I changed my code as     var href = $(this).attr('href');         $('#content').load(href); and I get the same error. So far it work fine, despite I get the error

Step 1 - narrow down the exact problem.  Do you get the error on var href = $(this).attr("href") or do you get it on $("#content").load(href)?  What if you change the href to something else, eg a simple html file on your server (no js etc)?

Add console.log($.fn.jquery) inside the ready and tell us the result.

Can you please provide your html

Without seeing your html its a guess, but you probably fire the event through elements that arent links. Try changing it to:
$(function() {
   $('.nav a, #menu a').click(function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      $('#content').load($(this).attr('href'));
   });
});

Or, to be super sure:
$(function() {
   $('.nav *[href], #menu *[href]').click(function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      $('#content').load($(this).attr('href'));
   });
});


.nav is the <ul> element, not the links, it doesn't have an href attribute.
You also have duplicate id="menu" elements. That isn't valid, because IDs must be unique, and #menu will only select the first one.
You should bind the handler to .nav .nav-link. This selects class="nav-link" within class="nav".


$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.nav .nav-link').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#content').load($(this).attr('href'));
  });
});
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
  <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-bs-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" data-bs-target="#submenu-3" aria-controls="submenu-3">Practice</a>
  <div id="submenu-3" class="collapse">
    <ul class="nav nav-small flex-column">

      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="practise.php">Practice</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="statistics.php">Statistics</a>
      </li>

    </ul>
  </div>
</li>



